# Android: Edit text, how to add invisible delimiters

Tags: android, android-edittext

**Background**

I want a single edit text that has three sections to it that I want to retrieve separately.

For example

```
First | Second | Third
```

**Idea**

My idea is for the underlying string to have some delimiter that I can use `indexOf` and `substring` etc. to retrieve the sections

For example "Hi my name is ||Tom|| I Like android"

**Problem**

The edit text shows the delimiter. Is there a way for the edit text to **not** **display** the delimiter but when I call:

```
String input = mEditText.getText().toString();
```

I get the text with the delimiters

Comment: What do you think about using a UTF-8 (or 16) [invisible separator](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2063/index.htm)? Would that solve your issue? You now just have to figure out where and when to place it etc. I mean there's not much context about that in your question :) Also, there's a `string.split()` method, usingthat rather than `indexOf` + `substring` might be easier.